# What are the allowed (supported) background image extensions in CSS3?

Tags: css, image, browser

I'm making a module using Php for generating image transforms for background images from an uploaded image in a CMS.

First step is checking the extension to see if the image is even allowed to be used for a background image. However I couldn't find information about this online.

```
background: url('image.extension');
```

Does anyone know if there are any?

Comment: You wan to check if the image extension is valid or not in css? if so I don't think there is anything like that unless if you can sort in js or jq.

Comment: `background-url` is not a css property, did you mean `background: url('...');`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I am sorry, I edited my question so it makes more sense.

Comment: @johannchopin Woops.. Edited the post.

Comment: @MikeSnoeren Every websites handle images in `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`. I thing with this 3 format you will have no problem with your client. Moreover there are all supported by the css property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp So in your case I will just make this 3 format available